# sql update in oracle statement using join

Tags: sql

please where is the error in this statement, I want to update a field1 of table 1 with field2 of table 2 joining both tables on a field 3

```
UPDATE 
     (SELECT IP_ANAGRAFICACOMPLESSO.id_complesso, COORDOK6.AZIENDA , IP_ANAGRAFICACOMPLESSO.COORD_GB_E,  COORDOK6.WGSE 
      FROM ip_anagraficacomplesso 
      INNER JOIN COORDOK6  ON IP_ANAGRAFICACOMPLESSO.ID_COMPLESSO = COORDOK6.AZIENDA )
SET IP_ANAGRAFICACOMPLESSO.COORD_GB_E = COORDOK6.WGSE
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which flavor of SQL you are using, but at least in TSQL you would need to rearrange it so the `SELECT` comes after the `SET`

```
UPDATE IP
SET IP.COORD_GB_E = C.WGSE
FROM IP_ANAGRAFLICACOMPLESSO IP
    INNER JOIN COORDOK6 C ON IP.ID_COMPLESSO = C.AZIENDA
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform such an `UPDATE` in ORACLE, your query should be as below. Always remember to create the appropriate join or else you might end up updating the wrong records.

```
 update DAILY D
  set
    (
      D.DEPARTMENT_CODE,
      D.COSTCENTRE_CODE,
      D.USER_ID
    )
    =
    (select distinct DEPT.DEPT_CODE,
      DEPT.CENTRE_CODE,
      PRT.EMP_ID
    from EMP PRT
    inner join DEPT  DEPT
    on DEPT.DEPARTMENT_ID = PRT.DEPARTMENT_ID
    where PRT.LOGIN_ID     = D.LOGIN_ID
    );
```

Comment: FYI, my query tries to perform an update to the daily table by matching the login_id info with the employee and department table

Answer (score 0):

According to this URL, the syntax is:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm

(ORACLE-provided syntax example):

```
   UPDATE employee_temp SET (first_name, last_name) =
  (SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees
   WHERE employee_id = employee_temp.employee_id);
```

Which would be something like this: You can only select one column
from the SELECT subquery - make sure the subquery is a valid INNER JOIN
with respect to your column and table names:

```
 UPDATE  COORD_GB_E
 SET     IP_ANAGRAFICACOMPLESSO =

 (SELECT COORDOK6.WGSE 
  FROM   ip_anagraficacomplesso INNER JOIN COORDOK6  
  ON     IP_ANAGRAFICACOMPLESSO.ID_COMPLESSO = COORDOK6.AZIENDA );
```

This documentation states if there is one column being updated to omit the parentheses around the updated column.